# Weird error in "insert into" command?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I know this may sound rubbish but that's the truth.

everytime when i try to run this code i get syntax error.

any idea why?

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Rock.accdb";
            con.Open();
            String query = "insert into category ([name],desc) values (@1,@2)";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            textBox1.Text = null;
            textBox2.Text = null;
            label4.Text = "New Category Created";
            label4.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

the error is: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement @ cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**desc** is also a keyword (for descending) and so you'd need:

```
String query = "insert into category ([name],[desc]) values (@1,@2)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `insert` query like this,

```
String query = "insert into category ([name], [desc]) values (@1,@2)";
```

desc is reserved word by default. Also, please close  your connection by `con.Close();` after executing the command.

Comment: Or even better, wrap the _OleDbCommand_ and the _OleDbConnection_ up in _using_ blocks so they automagically dispose.